# MVC3 : How to map HARDCODED anchor tag to virtual path of deployment environment?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url, iis-7.5, anchor, virtual-directory

I have deployed MVC3 website on IIS 7.5 with Integrated mode .Net4.0.
We have used anchor tag as under to move to specific action methods.

```
<a href="/Controller/Action">linkText</a>
```

These tags are working fine in development environment (in VS2010). But when we deployed it, they are not working since URLs are not mapped to proper virtual path.

If we replace all anchor tags with

```
@Html.ActionLink("linkText", "Action", "Controller")
```

or

```
@Url.Action("linkText", "Action", "Controller")
```

than it will be working fine.

But this change need to be done at so many places. **Is there any way so that we can make chages at minimum places and it will start working?**

Comment: You should switch to the Helper method approach. They were created for poeople like us to use. Never hardcode. It may take some time to fix it today. But you will be happy in future.

Answer (score 0):

I think adding **~** will solve your problem.

```
<a href="~/Controller/Action">linkText</a>
```

Comment: It is not working Ibrahim. It is generating html like <a href="~/Controller/Action"> linkText </a> in browser but not serving the need. Thanks for your attempt though.